# UITextField Issue With TextField Effects

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

Hello Everyone when I am using UITextField Effect(HosiTextField Effect) on my story board but it is not working properly it is showing iPhone 7,6s,8 but other some devices it is not showing when I am running my project.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PHx2.png

Comment: Could you Please show your code ?

Comment: Are you testing your code in simulator or device?

Comment: @DixitAkabari I am not using any code for the UITextField Effect simply I installed a pod for it and gave all effects from storyboard

Comment: @iPeter.  Currently I am testing on Simulator.

Comment: @veerendrapratapsingh Run your project in device instead of simulators. It always show you that bottom line. In simulator, very thin lines are sometimes not shown. Even you face same issue when you use tableview seperator.

Comment: Check one thing, change all of your simulator device's scale to 100%, you might see the bottom line. It gets hidden sometimes when you check your application in simulator in low scaling.

Comment: @dahiya_boy. thanks buddy its working fine .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved the answer of this question.

Problem is that. if I was running on simulator. it was not showing me properly. But, When I run on Real Device (Means iPhone ) It was working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, so I opened an issue because the test results are from the ipad (not simulator), but apparently he had no solution yet as he did not experienced the problem before. It also happened when trying to run the demo project:

https://github.com/raulriera/TextFieldEffects/issues/144